# JavaFX 8: Atualizando o TableView após o fechamento da janela

Tags: java, javafx

Eu tenho uma tela de cadastro de classificações e uma de gerenciamento de classificações, de um sistema de biblioteca. Após cadastrar uma nova classificação, eu gostaria que a TableView de classificações, na tela de gerenciamento, fosse atualizada mostrando o novo registro. Eu refaço a consulta no banco e passo os valores da nova consulta para a lista, porém ele não atualiza na tela.
Aqui eu chamo o método para refazer a consulta após salvar as informações no banco:

```
{Rotina que salva a informação no banco}
GerenciarClassificacoesController controller = new GerenciarClassificacoesController(); 
controller.atualizarTableView();
```

Aqui é onde ele refaz a consulta e seta os itens na TableView:

```
public class GerenciarClassificacoesController(){
    @FXML
    private void TableView<ClassificacaoLivro> tableClassificacoes;
    ...
    public void atualizarTableView(){
         itens = FXCollections.observableArrayList(servico.getClassificacoes());
         tableClassificacoes.setItems(itens);
         tableClassificacoes.refresh();
    }
}
```

Ele cai no método atualizarTableView, ele refaz a consulta no banco e traz as informações certas, mas ele não seta na TableView. Por favor, me ajudem :p 
NOTA: Esse mesmo método (atualizarTableView) é chamado no initialize da tela, e funciona corretamente, quando eu chamo de fora (outro arquivo) ele não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você está criando uma nova instância de GerenciarClassificacoesController, por isso nada é atualizado. Você deve passar a instância atual dele para o controller de cadastro e chamar o método atualizarTableView() a partir dessa instância.
Exemplo:

```
CadastroClassificacoesController cadastro controller = fxmlloader.getController();
cadastro.setGerenciadorController(this); // caso esteja chamando a partir dele mesmo
...
```

No CadastroClassificacoesController mude seu metodo de cadasro para:

```
{Rotina que salva a informação no banco}
gerenciadorController.atualizarTableView();
```